# CodeIgniter - How to dynamically select a menu item in a partial view page for menu?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, partial-views

Basically, I have a menu, which works as a navigation to different pages in my application containing the title of those pages. This menu is created as a partial view. I've a folder named **'partials'**, inside I've my menu partial view page named **'menu_view.php'**. Here's the code of **'menu_view.php'**:

```
<div id="menu" class="box">


    <ul class="box">
        <li id="<?php if(isset($controller_name)) echo 'selected'; ?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin_logins"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li id="<?php if(isset($controller_name)) echo 'selected'; ?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin_logins/meal2"><span>Add Meal</span></a></li>
        <li id="<?php if(isset($controller_name)) echo 'selected'; ?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin_logins/designation"><span>Designation</span></a></li>
        <li id="<?php if(isset($controller_name)) echo 'selected'; ?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin_logins/employee2"><span>Employee</span></a></li>
        <li id="<?php if(isset($controller_name)) echo 'selected'; ?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin_logins/role"><span>Role</span></a></li>
        <li id="<?php if(isset($controller_name)) echo 'selected'; ?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin_logins/user"><span>User</span></a></li>
        <li id="<?php if(isset($controller_name)) echo 'selected'; ?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin_logins/meal"><span>Meal Information</span></a></li>
        <li id="<?php if(isset($controller_name)) echo 'selected'; ?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin_logins/meal_bill_config"><span>Meal Bill Configuration</span></a></li>
        <li id="<?php if(isset($controller_name)) echo 'selected'; ?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/report_meal_lists/index"><span>Reports</span></a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

In order to show a certain menu item as selected, I've added an array index named **'controller_name'** in the respective controller method. For instance, for the **'Designation'** title to be selected, I've added the following to my controller method:

```
function designation() {

        //i've written controller's specific code here. 
        //i'm not showing this as it has no relation with the question

        $data["controller_name"] = 'admin_logins/designation';
        $this->load->view('/admin_logins/designation_view', $data);
}
```

In the view page('/admin_logins/designation_view'), I've got this:

```
 $this->load->view('partials/menu_view', $controller_name);
```

But I don't get my menu item to be selected.

What am I doing wrong?

Note that designation, and most other titles in my menu are from methods of a single controller named **'admin_logins'**, it is understandable from my code for **'menu_view.php'**.

CodeIgniter - 2.2.0, PHP - 5.3.0

Comment: Shouldn't your condition be more specific? I mean, you should compare its name and not just check if it's set. Otherwise - you get the same result (true/false) for all of the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each list item would require an if statement, like this;

```
<ul class="box">
    <li id="<?php if(isset($controller_name) == 'admin_logins') echo 'selected'; ?>"><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin_logins'); ?>">Home</a></li>
    <li id="<?php if(isset($controller_name) == 'admin_logins/meal2') echo 'selected'; ?>"><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin_logins/meal2'); ?>">Meal</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

So you're checking if $controller_name is set, and if it matches the string.

I also notice you're using "base_url()" for your links, it would make your life easier to use "site_url()" which adds the index.php itself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried your solution but it doesn't work. I suspect my partial view page - **menu_view.php** is not getting the **$controller_name** variable, maybe that's the reason behind this not working.

Comment: I've done <?php echo "<pre>"; print_r($controller_name); die(); ?> in my view page. It shows a PHP error saying - `Undefined variable: controller_name`. And just out of curiosity, why did you put the word `getting` inside quotes?

Comment: In your "designation_view" change the code to this;

$data['controller_name'] = $controller_name;
 $this->load->view('partials/menu_view', $data);

Comment: I think you're passing the data to the view, then you're simply passing the controller name to the next view, not an array. No reason for the quotes.

Comment: Hmmm. I am a guy from a non-English speaking country, so maybe I said it wrong. I actually wanted to mean passing **$controller_name**. If I translate this into my local language, it sounds like "getting". Excuse my poor English then. :)